# customizing SSRS 2008 R2 Maps

Tags: geometry, ssrs-2008, gis, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to show sales on my country map via SSRS R2.
I downloaded *.shp files and it works fine.
now I want to split a city to 2 cities, and show its data, but I don't know how to do it.
I tried to split it via Autocad , and then convert it to shape but it removed my cities name !!!

how can I customize my map easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure if what you want is to preprocess the .shp (shape) files or do the processing in SQL server.

If you want to do preprocessing (manually) I suggest you use something like [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/), which is free and open source. Otherwise maybe you need to clarify your process in the question.

Comment: I downloaded QGIS but it was hard to work with it. but I downloaded MAP WINDOW, and it was great. you can download it from http://www.mapwindow.org/downloads/index.php?show_details=1

Comment: Do you know any other free application, which allows you to work with your shapefile like photoshop?

Comment: No, I am not aware of tools other than GIS tools (like map window and QGIS) to handle shape files (*.shp) easily.

Comment: I am also currently having the same issue. Did you get this rectified?